# Is that possible to have a Shamsi (persian) Calendar in Windows? What about Microsoft Office

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is there any solution for replacing the current Georgian Calendar of Microsoft Windows with [Shamsi (Persian) Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar)?

Although, Microsoft Excel and other packages of Microsoft Office must recognize this calendar.

If you know the answer, please tell me, what version of MS Windows is going to work with it:

- Windows XP
- Windows 7
- Windows 8

Comment: @Ashtray,Thanks A Lot,For Editing My Question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is no unless you use third party add ons.

[Microsoft Connect: Persian Hijri Shamsi Datetime, Status:Closed](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-start/persian-calendar-component-for-windows-7/022bb06d-c0de-48e4-a7a4-29a0fc87643c)

[Answers.microsoft.com: Persian calendar component for windows 7](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/472731/persian-hijri-shamsi-datetime)